# Is it possible for Django ModelForms to work with dynamically added fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've managed to get Django Forms to dynamically generate additional fields based on the relationship between a specific instance (eg. 'product type') and another model (eg. 'product attributes') eg. products have common attributes like weight and price but a book has a page count and a computer has specs.

I'd like to be able to do the same with ModelForms so that I can just call form.save() but I'm not sure what the right approach would be to do this or where to start. At first I thought it would be possible by overriding some of the methods but then I've looked around the models.py file and it seems that I'd need to add quite a bit of code at various places in there to handle the additional fields ie. quite a lot of work. Or am I missing the easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics, I'd say you're right. If the additional fields are not part of the model, then at the least, you'd have to override the ModelForm's save() method.